# can live tv stream in Google tv be included in an apk?

Tags: google-tv

Not looking to alter the stream just include a smaller window of the full unaltered stream, or even just allow the stream to be seen through transparency in the app. really the best scenario is one where we can shrink the full stream to 1/4 screen or so and include it in the app using an intent like videoview to display the liveview when necessary. i know that we have heard overlay is begin worked on, but what about inclusion with no overlay liek the live tv app does?

Answer (score 1):

You can't shrink the Live TV video.  You can use a long running Toast to put up an overlay.  Several apps do that.